# Leaflet colours for polylines

Tags: r, leaflet

I would like to use a basic data.frame to get three polylines each of different colours

I am currently using the below code as an example.

```
require(leaflet)
df <- data.frame(lat=c(rnorm(20,50),rnorm(40,0),rnorm(40,-30)),
                 lon=rnorm(100),
                 group=rep(c("a","b","c"),times=c(20,40,40)),
                 col=rep(rainbow(3,alpha=NULL),times=c(20,40,40)))
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(lng=~lon,lat=~lat,color=~col)
```

But I get one continous line and and not the three separate lines for each group.

I can separate the lines but doing an very inelegant trick of:

```
df_a <- rbind(df[df$group=="a",],data.frame(lat=NA,lon=NA,group="a",col=NA))
df_b <- rbind(df[df$group=="b",],data.frame(lat=NA,lon=NA,group="b",col=NA))
df_c <- rbind(df[df$group=="c",],data.frame(lat=NA,lon=NA,group="c",col=NA))
df <- rbind(df_a,df_b)
df <- rbind(df,df_c)
```

before the leaflet function, but it still does not solve the colour problem.

Any help to get the three polylines different colours would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to automate for each group in your dataset:

```
map <-  leaflet(df)
map <- addTiles(map)
for( group in levels(df$group)){
        map <- addPolylines(map, lng=~lon,lat=~lat,data=df[df$group==group,], color=~col)
        }
map
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this programmatically for any number of groups?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **mapview** which is based on **leaflet** (at least for small datasets) and has been designed for such particular tasks. The fundamental difference is that you are required to convert `df` to an object of class `SpatialLines*` before you can pass the data on to `mapview`. Here is a short code snippet based on your sample data.

```
## load packages
library(sp)
library(mapview)

## sample data
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(lat = c(rnorm(20, 50), rnorm(40, 0), rnorm(40, -30)),
                 lon = rnorm(100),
                 group = rep(letters[1:3], times = c(20, 40, 40)),
                 col = rep(rainbow(3, alpha = NULL), times = c(20, 40, 40)), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## 'Lines' list
lst_lns <- lapply(letters[1:3], function(i) {
  df_sub <- subset(df, group == i)
  ln <- Line(df_sub[, 2:1])
  Lines(list(ln), ID = i)
})

## to 'SpatialLines'
sln <- SpatialLines(lst_lns, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

## to 'SpatialLinesDataFrame'
slndf <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sln, match.ID = FALSE, 
                               data = unique(df[, c("group", "col")]))

## display data
mapview(slndf, zcol = "group", color = slndf@data$col)
```

[image: grouped_lines]