# Change color of leaflet line accordingly with a vector

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there anyway to change the color of leaflet line base on the value of some variable? I google it, and found this [link](http://hgoebl.github.io/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/demo/).

However, I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it with leaflet in R. I tried something like:

```
data <- data.frame(long = runif(40,-10,10), lat = runif(40,50,60), speed = runif(40,0,100))
leaflet(data) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, color = ~speed)
```

but, it shows only one color.

Comment: have you looked into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143155/leaflet-colours-for-polylines

Comment: I did.. However, they consider only groups there. In my case, the color should follow a continuous variable rather than discretized ones.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a reproducible example with sample data.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90201/80952

Comment: I've added some sample data to make the example reproducible