# Different color addPolylines in Leaflet R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, polyline

I have a shiny app that is a basically a leaflet with polylines that go from one lat/long to another.

I want to have some polylines be blue and some be green.

However, I am not getting this to work. This is the data I am giving the function:

[image]

This is the function:

```js
m = addPolylines(m, lng = data_subset()$long,
  lat = data_subset()$lat,
  color = data_subset()$color,
  group = data_subset()$group
)
```

The output map has all the lines green however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet colours for polylines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143155/leaflet-colours-for-polylines)

Comment: answer can be found at the duplicate link...

Comment: Thanks, that works. I can't believe I didn't find that post, I searched for bare time.